# html5 canvas shapes fill

Tags: html, canvas

I have a basic paint application on a canvas, and I want to make a drawing-border and by that create a stencil. In other words, I want to make a shape, and then I want the user to be able to draw only inside it, even when he tries to draw outside.

Do you have any idea how can i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by making a clipping region. The basic idea is that there is a path on the canvas that all drawing is constrained to.

Make the shape, and instead of calling `stroke()` or `fill()`, call `clip()`

If you don't quite get how clipping regions work, there are a few [examples](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/) around.